# how can i move my custom button down on my game

Tags: java, graphics2d

so I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3GY_VHsWDc&list=PLmnre1rRSPjEbhc9JcIC5bwnazdjnL_L1&index=35/) for how to make a 2D game and my button does not, want to go to the place i specify i am going to put the code i have on a separate site as its connected to other classes I've made. but this is the class I'm looking at: MenuState:

```
package game.dl.gamestates;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import game.dl.Managers.MouseManager;
import game.dl.gamestate.GameState;
import game.dl.gamestate.GameStateManager;
import game.dl.gamestate.gameStateButton;
import game.dl.main.Main;

public class MenuState extends GameState {

    MouseManager mm;
    gameStateButton startGame;

    public MenuState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);

    }

    @Override
    public void init() {

        startGame = new gameStateButton(Main.width / 2, 200, new DungeonLvlLoader(gsm), gsm, "start Game");
        mm = new MouseManager();

    }

    @Override
    public void tick(double deltaTime) {
        mm.tick();
        startGame.tick();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics2D g) {
        startGame.render(g);
        mm.render(g);
//      g.drawString("TESTING", Main.width, Main.height);
//      g.drawString("Hello World!", 150, 200);
        g.clipRect(0, 0, Main.width, Main.height);

    }

}
```

this is the GameStateButton.java class:

```
package game.dl.gamestate;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import game.dl.Managers.MouseManager;
import game.dl.main.Assets;
import game.gos.main.VectorToF;

public class gameStateButton extends Rectangle{

    private VectorToF pos = new VectorToF();
    private GameState gameState;
    private GameStateManager gsm;
//  private boolean isClicked;
    private boolean isHeldOver;
    private int width = 32 *3;
    private int height = 32;
    private BufferedImage defaultImage;
    private String buttonMsg;


    public gameStateButton(float xpos, float ypos, GameState gameState, GameStateManager gsm, String buttonMsg) {
        this.gameState = gameState;
        this.gsm = gsm;
        this.pos.xpos = pos.xpos;
        this.pos.ypos = pos.ypos;
        this.buttonMsg = buttonMsg;
        setBounds((int)pos.xpos, (int)pos.ypos, width, height);
        defaultImage = Assets.getButton_notHoveredOver();
    }

    public gameStateButton(float xpos, float ypos, String buttonMsg) {
        this.pos.xpos = pos.xpos;
        this.pos.ypos = pos.ypos;
        this.buttonMsg = buttonMsg;
        setBounds((int)pos.xpos, (int)pos.ypos, width, height);
        defaultImage = Assets.getButton_notHoveredOver();
    }

    public void tick(){
        setBounds((int)pos.xpos, (int)pos.ypos, width, height);

        if(getBounds().contains(MouseManager.mouse)){
            isHeldOver = true;
        }else{
            isHeldOver = false;
        }

        if(isHeldOver){
            if(defaultImage != Assets.getButton_hoveredOver()){
                defaultImage = Assets.getButton_hoveredOver();
            }

        }else{
            if(defaultImage != Assets.getButton_notHoveredOver()){
                defaultImage = Assets.getButton_notHoveredOver();
            }
        }

        if(gameState != null){
            if(isHeldOver){
                if(isPressed()){
                    gsm.states.push(gameState);
                    isHeldOver = false;
                    MouseManager.pressed = false;
                }
            }
        }


    }

    public void render(Graphics2D g){
        g.drawImage(defaultImage, (int)pos.xpos, (int)pos.ypos, width, height, null);
        g.drawString(buttonMsg, pos.xpos, pos.ypos);
    }

//  public boolean isClicked(){
//      return isClicked;
//  }
    public boolean isHeldOver(){
        return isHeldOver;
    }

    public boolean isPressed (){
        return MouseManager.pressed;
    }

}
```

this is the full code dump: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7JJSxzNdpBrNmdFRTgyVXhRSVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Where is the button showing up

Comment: What is the purpose of setting the clip rectangle AFTER you do the rendering? Also, note that `g.clipRect()` can only be used to make the clip rectangle smaller than it currently is; you need to use `setClipRect()` to make it larger.

Comment: the 'g.clipRect()' was a "quick" fix for a problem and i just haven't taken it out yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after playing around and looking at my other classes for a while I found the problem. in gameStateButton.java the constructor was pulling the x and y pos from the class fields and not the constructor variable so it should look like this:

```
public gameStateButton(float xpos, float ypos, GameState gameState,     GameStateManager gsm, String buttonMsg) {
    this.gameState = gameState;
    this.gsm = gsm;
    this.pos.xpos = xpos;
    this.pos.ypos = ypos;
    this.buttonMsg = buttonMsg;
    setBounds((int)pos.xpos, (int)pos.ypos, width, height);
    defaultImage = Assets.getButton_notHoveredOver();
}
```

and **NOT** this:

```
public gameStateButton(float xpos, float ypos, GameState gameState, GameStateManager gsm, String buttonMsg) {
    this.gameState = gameState;
    this.gsm = gsm;
    this.pos.xpos = pos.xpos;
    this.pos.ypos = pos.ypos;
    this.buttonMsg = buttonMsg;
    setBounds((int)pos.xpos, (int)pos.ypos, width, height);
    defaultImage = Assets.getButton_notHoveredOver();
}
```

Comment: Yes. But you should still edit the question and add the relevant bit of code there for everyone to see what you are talking about :) Your link will eventually expire and this knowledge will be lost otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Your gameStateButton class is initialized as:

```
startGame = new gameStateButton(Main.width / 2, 200, new DungeonLvlLoader(gsm), gsm, "start Game");
```

Looking inside your code zip (btw, next time add the gameStateButton.java code here), you have a fixed width of 32*3 pixel and 32 pixel height for the button.

You are setting it at x = Main.width/2, y=200.

You can change those values to be whatever you want.

Now you have not told us what is the actual result (i.e. where it shows now), nor what is the expected result (i.e. where you want it to be), but that line is what is defining its initial position: if it doesn't show there, then something is changing its place. If it doesn't show at all, then probably you are drawing it in the wrong order and it gets overwritten.

Comment: the button shows up in the upper left corner of the screen, but i want it to be in the center which is about x-550 y - 550